# How to get a line with a string from multiple files by file orders?

Tags: linux

Related to my previous question....

I want to get a line where the first column has a certain string from 5000 files.
But I want to show the lines in the output file by the order of input files.
For example,

File_1

```
agd fkg fls  ofk
ggs kkg ikg  gkl
bsg ksf olg  lzj
many more lines,,,
kgf kkg ikg  lgk
```

File_2

```
gik zlg olg  pzk
ppl sjg gol  dzj
zjg iwj bmh  hgi
many more lines,,,
kgf wlg ugk  lkf
```

many more files...

Output_file

```
kgf kkg ikg lgk  -- This line from the File_1
kgf wlg ugk lkf  -- This is from the File_2
more lines...
kgf ald fig wdg  -- This last line is from the File_5000
```

Just getting a line from multiple files can be as below.

```
grep -rEh `kgf` File_* > Output_file
```

But if I do this, output_file shows lines in the random order. The first line of the Output file can be from File_20 or others, and not the File_1. So I want the output_file to show the line from File_1 in the first line of output file, File_2 to be the 2nd line of output file, File_3 to be the 3rd of output file, etc.

Does anybody know this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the expansion of `File_*` is not random. Shell globbing sorts the filenames lexically (using `strcmp()` (byte to byte comparison) or `strcoll()` (user's locale collation order) depending on the shell).

That means however that `File_10` will come *before* `File_2`.

For a numeric order, you can use the `zsh` shell and do:

```
grep -h '^kgf' File_*(n) > Output_file
```

Where the `n` glob qualifier turns on the `numericglobsort` option (another `zsh`-specific feature) for the expansion of that glob only.

If on a GNU system (the `-h` option which you're using is already a GNU extension) and with any shell, you could do something similar with:

```
printf '%s\0' File_* | sort -zV | xargs -r0 grep -h '^kgf' > Output_file
```

Where `sort -V` is a *version* sort which behaves similarly to `zsh`'s *numeric* glob sort.